# Clear function name that indicates it will return a Promise (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, promise, code-readability

I wanted to know if there was a naming convention that I should follow for functions that return a promise that clearly explained that `.then()` should be added if you expect to have the promise work.

I modified an old function `addFilterForLanguage(lang)` to return a promise for downloading that language's filter.  In the past, it wasn't an asynchronous task, and filter would be called before it had arrived.  I want a better name to clearly indicate that `.then()` is necessary.  We often have new interns (one of which wrote the original code) who might not know about promises, and often assume that it would/will "just work."

Is there a convention for this yet, or is `addFilterForLanguage_ButDontForgetToCall_Then_AndPassInAFunctionIfYouWantItToRunToMakeItSyncronous(lang)` the best I can do?

(I thought `addFilterForLanguage(lang).then(myFunction)` was clear enough, but you never know.)

Comment: The best you can do is to document your code properly, add jsdoc comments like `@return {Promise}`, etc.

Comment: How about something like `addFilterForLanguageAsync` The hope being that any new intern might at least say "hey! what's this `async` thing about?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) Promise library adds `Async` as a suffix to a function name when you use `Promise.promisifyAll` on a Node-style callback function.

For instance, transforming `fs.exists` with `promisifyAll` will turn it into `fs.existsAsync`.

We've used that convention in any code where Promises need to interact with Node-style callbacks.

Comment: Referencing the Bluebird library was a nice touch.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is something that is either implemented as a coding guideline within teams or it's not. In the past, I have worked on teams, were we decided to add an Async suffix to anything that returned a promise, so in you case, addFilterForLanguageAsync.